# Contains matches on pairs of items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a mapping table in the following form:

```
Id  ReferenceId  ReferenceType LinkId
```

To retrieve a set of combinations, I could run each query separately:

```
var pairs = new List<Pair>
{
    Pair.Create(1000, "Car"),
    Pair.Create(2000, "Truck"),
};
var maps = new List<Mapping>();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    maps.AddRange(context.Mappings.Where(x => x.ReferenceId = pair.Id && x.ReferenceType == pair.Type).ToList());
}
```

However, I want to combine these into a single statement to reduce my hits on the db.  Is there some form of Contains statement that can work with pairs of objects?  Or is it possible to append an OR clause onto an IQueryable within a loop?  Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it works for your LINQ provider but you could try to join with an anonymous type:

```
var mapQuery = from p in pairs 
               join m in context.Mappings
               on new { p.Id, p.Type } equals new { m.ReferenceId, m.ReferenceType}
               select m;
List<Mapping> maps = mapQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: @Savage I'm curious: which LINQ provider is this? I'm not aware of any LINQ/SQL-provider that supports this, because there's no way to translate the anonymous types into SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold - I suspect it's `linq-to-entities ` cz he got `NotSupportedException` when OP tried with `Any`, see exception details in my deleted answer :)

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes, that's EF. Still I wonder why this is an accepted answer. I think the OP has used `context.Mappings.AsEnumerable()` to make it work. Would be nice to know for sure, otherwise this is kind of confusing for future readers.

Comment: I am using this on top of EF6 and it's working.  Here is my actual code in the end:

`var mapQuery = from p in mappings
                           join m in dbContext.ChargeGroupMaps
                           on new { p.ReferenceId, p.ReferenceType } equals new { m.ReferenceId, m.ReferenceType }
                           select m;
            var chargeGroupIds = mapQuery.Select(x => x.ChargeGroupId).ToList();`

Comment: Ah, I see. When joined in this order, EF decides to execute everything in memory. *In fact* it does `dbContext.ChargeGroupMaps.AsEnumerable()`. To me, that's not an acceptable strategy. This behavior must have changed recently and I'm not happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx) your queries together.

Something like this:

```
var pairs = new List<Pair>
{
    Pair.Create(1000, "Car"),
    Pair.Create(2000, "Truck"),
};

List<Mapping> result =
    pairs
    .Select(pair =>
        context.Mappings.Where(
            x => x.ReferenceId == pair.Id
            && x.ReferenceType == pair.Type))
    .Aggregate(Queryable.Union)
    .ToList();
```